# Prove there's finitely points in K such that K is a subset of the finite union of finitely many epsilon-neighborhoods of said points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm completely lost of where to start on this problem, my prof said as a hint to use the fact that every neighborhood is open

Comment: Did you forget to mention that $K$ is a compact set? What you then have to show is that compact sets are totally bounded. What do you know about the theorem of Heine-Borel? What is your definition of a compact space, coverings or sequences?

Answer (score 0):

The collection of open balls $\{B(x,ϵ):x\in K\}$ trivially covers $K$.

As a compact set, one can select a finite subset of that collection that is still covering $K$.